# Promoting retro appropriate sites on SE Retro

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion

Many SE sites have a place for "community ads" on the right-hand side. SE Retrocomputing itself was promoted on SE Electronics (and possibly others.)

It can also be a place for non SE sites of potential interest. Again, on the Electronics SE, the famous EE Blog is often promoted, because it is of interest to the community there. I'm sure there are others, and it might even be a way to aggregate all those existing, but perhaps less visited sites we've bookmarked over the years.

As a suggestion for this site, there is a *lot* of retrocomputing stuff over on hackaday.com and the sister site hackaday.io.

Is this something we want to do for SE Retro? I recall it is as easy as having folks on meta present examples in the expected format, but I'm ignorant of the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature you're referring to is called *Community promotion ads*. [This](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/community-promotion-ads-2016) is an example of a meta thread you mention (follow the link for the rules).

Community promotion ads are only possible when a site “graduates”, i.e. when it's reached the last stage after private beta (normally 3 weeks) and public beta (as long as it takes to reach a point where the site is clearly heading for success, [officially defined as a steady 10 questions per week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)).

Answer (score 5):

I suppose so but probably during public beta.

Help on retro machinery in general is pretty rare nowadays so some ads could help out, even answer some of the questions! But ads this early with deviate us in the wrong path I believe. We should be more focused on moderating and producing high quality content so this site reaches public beta. *Then* we can take care of the ads, about us and for us.

Comment: s/but probably/but not probably/

Comment: @jdv Sorry, I need to implement Perl RegEx on my Commodore 64 before I can read your comment, as it seems to be in some sort of foreign language.

Comment: Those ads won't be available until when the beta ends anyway.

Comment: To follow-up, I wasn't suggesting we do this _yesterday_, but wanted to table it for discussion.